# Same output no matter the input

Tags: c

So I'm writing this program to be a two player game of paper rock scissors, and no matter what each player chooses, the output is "Player 1 wins."

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
long player1Choice, player2Choice, p, r, s;


        printf("Player 1, enter paper (p), rock (r), or scissors (s)\n");
            player1Choice=getchar();
            getchar();

        printf("Player 2, enter paper (p), rock (r), or scissors (s)\n");
            player2Choice=getchar();
            getchar();

        if((player1Choice=p)&&(player2Choice=r))    
            printf("Player 1 wins!\n");
        else if((player1Choice=r)&&(player2Choice=p))
            printf("Player 2 wins!\n");
        else if((player1Choice=r)&&(player2Choice=s))
            printf("Player 1 wins!\n");
        else if((player1Choice=s)&&(player2Choice=r))
            printf("Player 2 wins!\n");
        else if((player1Choice=s)&&(player2Choice=p))
            printf("PLayer 1 wins!\n");
        else if((player1Choice=p)&&(player2Choice=s))
            printf("Player 2 wins!\n");


    printf("Press any key to exit");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I think the logical "and"s in my "if" statements may be causing the trouble, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's like 20th question about RPS in last 2 days. School started somewhere? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `p`, `r`, and `s`, but you never initialize them.  You also are using assignment (`=`) rather than a test for equality (`==`). Your program causes undefined behaviour.  It looks like you intended something along the lines of:

```
if ((player1Choice == 'p') && (player2Choice == 'r'))
```

After fixing those, you can get rid of the spurious variables.  Alternately, change your variable declarations to include initialization:

```
long player1Choice, player2Choice, p = 'p', r = 'r', s = 's';
```

You'll still need to fix your `=` problem.

You should turn more warnings on in your compiler.  For example, for your program, from Clang:

```
$ clang -Wall example.c -o example
example.c:19:51: warning: variable 's' is uninitialized when used here
      [-Wuninitialized]
        else if((player1Choice=r)&&(player2Choice=s))
                                                  ^
example.c:4:43: note: initialize the variable 's' to silence this warning
long player1Choice, player2Choice, p, r, s;
                                          ^
                                           = 0
example.c:15:27: warning: variable 'p' is uninitialized when used here
      [-Wuninitialized]
        if((player1Choice=p)&&(player2Choice=r))    
                          ^
example.c:4:37: note: initialize the variable 'p' to silence this warning
long player1Choice, player2Choice, p, r, s;
                                    ^
                                     = 0
example.c:15:46: warning: variable 'r' is uninitialized when used here
      [-Wuninitialized]
        if((player1Choice=p)&&(player2Choice=r))    
                                             ^
example.c:4:40: note: initialize the variable 'r' to silence this warning
long player1Choice, player2Choice, p, r, s;
                                       ^
                                        = 0
3 warnings generated.
```

Comment: Thanks, guys - that totally slipped past me.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing single quotes around your character constants and also using `=` when you need `==`. So change e.g.

```
    if((player1Choice=p)&&(player2Choice=r))
```

to:

```
    if((player1Choice=='p')&&(player2Choice=='r'))
```

Do this for all similar occurrences.

Also get rid of the unused variable, `r`, `p`, and `s`.

And finally, **turn on compiler warnings and take notice of them** - the compiler would have helped you fix all these problems if you had allowed it to.